# Js if/else statement not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the width and height of certain images equal (or, more specific: the div around it), but somehow it doesn't seem to work.. Anyone who can help?

```
$('.a2paragraph .image img').each(function() {
    var img = $('.a2paragraph .image img');

    var h = img.height(),
        w = img.width();

    if (h > w) {
        img.parent().css('height', w);
    }
    else if (w < h) {
        img.parent().css('width', h);
    }


});
```

EDIT: changed the code, but still not working:

```
$('.a2paragraph .image img').each(function() {
    var img2 = $('.a2paragraph .image img');

    var h = img2.height(),
        w = img2.width();

    if (h > w) {
        img2.parent().css('height', w);
    }
    else if (h < w) {
        img2.parent().css('width', h);
    }


})
```

Comment: So you have an image with an id "img"? I doubt that is what you want. DOM does not have height() and width(). You are mixing up jQuery and DOM.

Comment: Yeah it was just to test it, but that isn't the error though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: Error is the fact is your test is wrong

Comment: `h>w` and `w<h` are the same condition.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (h > w) {
    img.parent().css('height', w);
}
else if (w < h) {
    img.parent().css('width', h);
}
```

The `if` and the `else if` conditions are the same. You're checking for `h > w` twice, just written in different orders.

Comment: plus it misses the case where `h=w`

Comment: @MarcB Does not matter since setting the opposite to equal the other is the same thing...

Comment: Oh!! Haha wow that's stupid.. Thanks a lot. No it doesn't have to do anything when they're equal :)

Comment: `img` contains all images and therefor returns always the height and width of the first image. Change it to `var img = $(this)` instead

Comment: @Andreas ah okay, thanks! Changed it but doesn't solve it though.. it just doesn't add the css to img.parent() ?